# Saving a Vector of Object to SharedPreferences using Gson

Tags: object, vector, sharedpreferences, gson

I'm saving a vector to sharedpreferences using Gson

This is my setters and getters but I seem to have some warning on my getter.

My setter doesn't have any warnings

```
     Gson gson = new Gson();
     String json = gson.toJson(al);
     editor.putString("accountLabels", json);
     editor.commit();
```

My getter warns me "Type safety: The expression of type Vector needs unchecked conversion to conform to Vector"

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = myPref.getString("accountLabels", "Error");
    Vector<AccountLabels> obj = gson.fromJson(json, Vector.class);
    return obj;
```

I don't know how much of a work around it is to save objects or even vector of objects in sharedpreferences, but it seems like the best solution for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the question is.  I'm guessing it's to do with resolving the unchecked conversion warning.  To do that, change

```
Vector<AccountLabels> obj = gson.fromJson(json, Vector.class);
```

to

```
Vector<AccountLabels> obj = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<Vector<AccountLabels>>(){}.getType());
```

The warning is occurring because the `fromJson` method is returning type `Vector`, but it's being assigned to a reference of type `Vector<AccountLabels>`.

(Note: Since 2001 (I think) and the newer Collections API, [use of `Vector` is frowned upon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated).)

Comment: Yes it is about the warning, thanks for the answer it helps. Also that's good to know. It's kind of disappointing as well as Vectors are so portable.